# Specific text code brings lot of hyphenation

Tags: texstudio, hyphenation, pdfpages

I am writing a document that has currently 83 pages and when I add the following text code into the `.tex` file, output `pdf` file increases to 85 ; addition of two pages instead of one.

There is almost no hyphenation in my entire document, except the one in `bibliography`. But this text code brings a lot more hyphenations.

I want to create the text on new page but without running into the problem of hyphenation. What's wrong with this code? Why it's making hyphenation?

Note: I am just including the specific `code` and relevant `packages`. Please mention if I should include some additional information into the `mwe`.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=12,          
BCOR=5mm,       
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\huge\textbf {Eidesstattliche Erklärung }\\[15mm]
\end{center}
  Hiermit erkläre ich xxx.
  München, am \\[10mm]
  \noindent\rule{4.8cm}{0.4pt}\\[1mm]
  Author

%Problematic code starts here 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}

\large Technische Universität München\\
\large Lehrstuhl für Hochspannungs- und Anlagentechnik\\
\large Fakultät für Elektrotechnik und Informationstechnik\\
\large Arcisstr. 21, 80333 München\\
\large Tel. +49 89 289 22002, Fax +49 89 289 25089\\
\large http://www.hsa.ei.tum.de
%Problematic code ends here 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are setting your whole document in \large. Add a group: `{\large Technische ....  http://... \par }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ulrike Fisher pointed, the problem was from the `\large` command, which was set for the whole document instead for just a small section.

Here is the complete working code:

```
\documentclass[
DIV=12,          
BCOR=5mm,       
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\huge\textbf {Eidesstattliche Erklärung }\\[15mm]
\end{center}
  Hiermit erkläre ich xxx.
  München, am \\[10mm]
 \noindent\rule{4.8cm}{0.4pt}\\[1mm]
  Author name

%Problematic code, corrected one!  
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}

{\large
Technische Universität München\\
Lehrstuhl für Hochspannungs- und Anlagentechnik\\
Fakultät für Elektrotechnik und Informationstechnik\\
Arcisstr. 21, 80333 München\\
Tel. +49 89 289 22002, Fax +49 89 289 25089\\
http://www.hsa.ei.tum.de}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The line spacing in the \large part is wrong. Add a \par before the closing brace,